# Getting error while passing a QString object to Parser::parse()

Tags: json, qt, qjson

I am reading a JSON file using Qfile. Storing it in to a `Qstring` object. While passing the `QStrin`g object to `Parser::parse()`, it is showing the compilation error as The function `parse()` only accepts `QIODevice*` or `const QByteArray&` as first argument.

The exact error message is:

```
no matching function for call to QJson::Parser::(QString,bool*)

candidates are Qvariant QJson::Parser::parse(QIODevice*,bool*)

note QVariant Qjson::Parser::parse(const QByteArray&,bool*)
```

I tried to cast `QString` to `QIODevice` and `QByteArray`, but all in vain.

Comment: Are you sure that is the _exact_ error message?  The first line "no matching function for call to QJson::Parser::(QString,bool*)" looks wrong, surely that should be `QJson::Parser::parse`?  Also, for help with compilation errors, please show the code as well as the errors.

Answer (score 1):

Use `QString::toUtf8()`, which converts a `QString` to a `QByteArray`

Comment: `QString::toAscii()` is only correct if he knows that the data will only contain ASCII characters. It will destroy non-ASCII data (e.g. Chinese, Japanese, Korean characters).  JSON usually uses UTF8 encoding, so `QString::toUtf8()` is most likely the right answer here.

Comment: after every thing also i m unable to run a web service and parse the json. pliz provide me a sample code to run webservice and read the json  and parse it. Actually this is my 1st app in Qt.